# Android Async Task Recycles Bitmap

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bitmap, android-asynctask

I want to store bitmap array to TextFile. So I am converting each Bitmap to Base64 String and joining it into a single string and storing in TextFile.

This works :

```
String imjCodSrg = getImjCodSrgFrmBitmapAryFnc(bitmapAryVar);
```

But it takes a long time so I am trying to put inside Async task or thread but get Recycled error.

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>()
{
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... ArgAryPsgVar)
    {
        String imjCodSrg = getImjCodSrgFrmBitmapAryFnc(bitmapAryVar);

        return null;
    }
}.execute();
```

|Or|

```
new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        String imjCodSrg = getImjCodSrgFrmBitmapAryFnc(bitmapAryVar);
    }
}).start();
```

|*| My helper functions :

```
// |==| Get Imj Byte Ary From Bitmap :

byte[] getImjBytAryFrmBitmapFnc(Bitmap srcImjBitmap)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream imjBytAryVar = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    srcImjBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, imjBytAryVar);
    return imjBytAryVar.toByteArray();
}

// |==| Get Image String Code From Bitmap Array :

String getImjCodSrgFrmBitmapAryFnc(List<Bitmap> srcImjBitmapVar)
{
    List<String> imjSrgCodAryVar = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Bitmap bitmapIdxVar : srcImjBitmapVar)
    {
        PrnFnc("bitmapIdxVar.isRecycled() : " + bitmapIdxVar.isRecycled());
        byte[] ImjBytAryIdxVar = getImjBytAryFrmBitmapFnc(bitmapIdxVar);
        String ImjCodSrgIdxVar = Base64.encodeToString(ImjBytAryIdxVar, Base64.DEFAULT);
        imjSrgCodAryVar.add(ImjCodSrgIdxVar);
    }
    return TextUtils.join("|", imjSrgCodAryVar);
}
```

I am not able to understand why AsyncTask or thread is making Bitmap recycle.

> I get the following error :
>
> D/TAG: bitmapIdxVar.isRecycled() : false
> D/TAG: bitmapIdxVar.isRecycled() : true

```
>   E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't compress a recycled bitmap
                     at android.graphics.Bitmap.checkRecycled(Bitmap.java:351)
                     at android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.java:1018)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - you should never store bitmap like this. By doing this will cause really large memory consumption. The right way to store images - save them into storage and write file path to your Database. [Here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/cache-bitmap.html) is helpful link for caching `Bitmaps`.

Comment: I am now trying to store it in a text file... but how to overcome recycled error.

Comment: No, I think you didn't quite get me. Don't store Bitmaps like this. Not in text file, not in any other file that is not "image/*"(mime type). Just save your `Bitmap` as file.jpg and that's it.

Comment: I don't want the images do be displayed in gallery. So I am writing in different format

Comment: If you'll put images in internal app storage - they will not be displayed in the gallery. Also as addition you can create `.nomedia` file in your internal app folder (Or maybe it's there by default).

Comment: I have no idea about storing images in internal app storage or using .nomedia.. If u can give steps to do that and suggest me a link wil be very helpful.

Comment: Storing files in internal app storage is the same as storing it elsewhere, just save images into path taken from `getFilesDir()`. This function will return `File` of internal app storage. And here is some info about `.nomedia` http://lifehacker.com/5793803/disable-media-scanning-in-specific-android-directories-by-creating-a-nomedia-file